# Django-reverse URL's

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I'm experimenting with Django forms. I'm trying to create a form which will accept the name of a city as input and output coordinates as output. My apps name is rango. I'm having a lot of trouble in URL reverse after accepting the input of the form..

My project/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
import os

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r'^rango/',include('rango.urls', namespace="rango")),
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
        'serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

My rango/urls.py (rango is the name of the app):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^welcome/$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about_page'),
        url(r'^categories/(?P<name_dir>\w+)/$',views.cats,name='cats'),
        url(r'^disp_page/(?P<city>\w+)/$',views.geo,name='coods'),
        url(r'^disp_page/$', views.disp_page, name='disp_page')
```

My forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from rango.models import Page, Category



class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the name of the city.")
    #url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the URL of the page.")
    #views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Page
        exclude = ('category','url','views')
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from rango.models import Category,Page
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
from rango.forms import PageForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import operator
# Create your views here.




def geo(request,city):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    citydata=Geocoder.geocode(city)
    codtuple=citydata[0].coordinates
    codtuple=list(codtuple)
    context_dict = {'cood':codtuple}

    return render_to_response('coods.html',context_dict,context)



def disp_page(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            #form.save(commit=True)
            city = form.cleaned_data['title']
           

           # context = RequestContext(request)

            #citydata=Geocoder.geocode(cityname)
            #codtuple=citydata[0].coordinates
            #codtuple=list(codtuple)
            #context_dict = {'cood':codtuple}
            
    
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rango:geo', args=(request,city)))

            
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = PageForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'disp_page.html', {'form': form})
```

Basically the disp_page displays the form. I type the name of a city in the form(EX:NEWYORK) and then it has to redirect to the "geo" function in my views.py which would output the coordinates in a different view. This redirection doesn't seem to be happening. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You have no named url called `geo`.

Comment: @limelights...Do I change url(r'^disp_page/(?P<city>\w+)/$',views.geo,name='coods'), to

Comment: Change `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rango:geo', args=(request,city)))` to `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rango:coods', args=(request,city)))`

Comment: @limelights...Still Doesnt work..:(..I keep getting the "NoReverseMatch at /rango/disp_page/" error

Comment: @limelights...Got it working!...Thanks...
1.I had to reference the url name as you told.
2.args(city,) works NOT args(request,city) as city was the only argument I was passing

Comment: Cool, happy hacking!

Comment: To import reverse, you now need to use `from django.urls.base import reverse`. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442844/django-reverse-function-import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line

```
url(r'^disp_page/(?P<city>\w+)/$',views.geo,name='coods'),
```

in `rango/urls.py` to :

```
url(r'^disp_page/(?P<city>\w+)/$',views.geo,name='geo'),
```

and use :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rango:geo', args=(city,)))
```