# django reverse function import

Tags: django

I've seen the following imports for function `reverse()`. All of them work, why? which one should I use?

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.urls.base import reverse
from django.core.urlresolver import reverse
from django.shortcuts import reverse
```

Comment: This reverse function originally defined in **`django.urls.base`**. Rest of the imports are used for the sake of simplicity/readability